# Yahoo Maps ASP.NET Intranet App Example

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know of any decent examples of using the royalty free yahoo maps functionality?

I can find lots of examples on google but in order to use google within an intranet they insist on your paying approximately £7k a year.

Any links greatly appreciated, ideally i'm thinking JQUERY plugin .js script and a sample ASP.NET page.

I'd like to display placeholders based on long and lat data in our database, on mouse-over the placeholders (or pins) i'd display additional information from the database, images, links etc

many thanks in advance

john

Comment: You should mark some of your questions with an answer. You have 12 questions and the majority have answers submitted. Why not acknowledge the people that have helped you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found just the thing at -> http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/maps/examples.html